# Can you use a regular URL to create a new font family in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, font-family

Hi I wanted to use a font in WPF without downloading the ttf.
The documentation on FontFamily class implied that I can use a http address as the base Uri for my font, however it doesn't seem to be working and I cannot find anywhere any working examples of how to do this.

So my code looks something like this

```
var newFont = new FontFamily(new Uri("http://myfontservice/myFont.ttf#myFont"), "myFont");
```

This is the most complex Uri I have tried. I've also tried a load of variations around the use of the font name but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT
Also worth noting the font service is just a folder on a machine that has been exposed over IIs. So the fonts are there as ttf files and the URL, if used in a browser, will download the ttf file.

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: No no errors, just that the font wasn't the expected font. I can use the URL and get the ttf file without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible as you expect it. According to [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Site of origin fonts:** WPF applications do not allow a font reference to an http or ftp uniform resource identifier (URI).

I guess the only hope is downloading it to a temp file and use a `file://` URI to load it

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the PrivateFontCollection doesn't work with WPF as it uses system.drawing.FontFamily not system.windows.media.FontFamily.

Comment: @Kezza you are indeed right... well, you could download the `TTF` to a temp file and then use a `file://` URI on the constructor. If you can't write temp files, I don't see a way to do it though (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I'll have to do. Was hoping to avoid writing to the file system.

Comment: @Kezza that's probably one of the many things missing in the half-bake WPF didn't ever get :-)